# Android: storing JSON data in singleton to pass between activities?

Tags: java, android

So let's say I have this list activity and when you click an item on the list it takes you to a new activity with more details on that list item. All this info is fetched using REST services. Before I'd use Retrofit to store that data into an object and store that into and singleton class that is accessible by both activities so that when one list item is selected it just takes the id and goes to the singleton to get the right data then use that in the new activity. Is this proper Android practice? Also I was wondering if it's better to have the list activity go to a new activity to present more detail info or use a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

It's your choice to take the details screen as Activity or Fragment.
Fragments are better.
And you can pass the list by making the pojo class as Parcelable between activities or fragments.

Comment: what is the "pojo class" and a parcelable? I'm very interested in becoming better at Android so if you wouldn't mind explaining those concepts it'd be very helpful.

Comment: pojo class has setters & getters and it is the type of List . For Example:- List<Item> mList; here, Item class is the pojo class which has variables like id of your item,name and other details of your item and have getters & setters method of all those variables. You can refer this link :-
https://www.quora.com/What-is-POJO-in-Java

Comment: Parcelable is an interface which converts your class in a stream and it is used to send the data of the class between the activities or fragments using intent.putParcelable() method. For better understanding of Parcelable, you can refer to this link:- 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable

Comment: THANKS! Really appreciate it. Cheers

Comment: Please upvote my answer..Thanks !! @DolanTheMFWizard

Answer (score 0):

Yes, usually we can use Static variables or singleton classes to transfer parameters between activities. You can also use intents to pass variables from one activity to another.